# How is a power cord connector polarized?

Tags: ac, connector, cables, polarity

For example, the common PC power cord cable (IEC 60320 C13).

[image: Power Connector]

How is it polarized if you can just switch the power plug upside down (EU)?
Does it have any internal circuitry?

Comment: It simply isn't.

Comment: If you can just plug it in up-side down, then it isn't polarized.  "Polarized" in this context means you _can't_ plug it in the wrong way.